# How to drag and drop an image from label to label?

Tags: java, image, swing, drag-and-drop, jlabel

I'm new in using the DnD in java.I'm trying to drag an drop an image from a label to another. The first label is the source, the second is the destination. My trouble is that I need to drag the image from the source and recognize that i'm dropping on the correct destination; if the destination is correct the image from the source must disappear, else must come back to the source and notify it to the user using a window message or just a `System.out.println()`. I've tried using `TransferHandler`, `DragSource`, but I didn't get a single good result.

How to drag and drop an image from label to label?

The Drag Listener

```
public class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);


        }
    }
```

The Source labels that contain the images

```
public ShipsGUI() {
    // setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 5));
    MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        JLabel a = new JLabel(ship,JLabel.CENTER);
        a.setName("ship");
        JLabel n = new JLabel("[" + Integer.toString(i + 1) + "]");
        n.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        // a.setBorderPainted(false);
        // a.setBackground(Color.white);
        // a.setOpaque(true);
        //a.setIcon(ship,JLabel.CENTER);
        a.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
        a.addMouseListener(listener);

        p.add(a);
        p.add(n, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(p);

    }
}
```

The destination (it's a grid fo labels)

```
public NewAreaGioco(int r,int c, boolean enable){


    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(r,c,1,1));

    for(int i=0;i<r;i++){           
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
            JLabel l= new JLabel(" ");          
            l.setSize(30, 30);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            if(enable)l.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));                
            add(l);
        }//fine for
    }//fine for
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DragandDropSupportforImages.htm) is a DnD example for images.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: Transfer the data, not the component for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844574/drag-and-drop-from-jbutton-to-jcomponent-in-java/28844969#28844969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't use the default TransferHandler class. You need to make your own.

I would start by looking at the `DropDemo` and `ListTransferHandler` class found on the examples page of the [Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/index.html#ListCutPaste) tutorial.

A couple of change that I think you will need to make:

1. export an image instead of text. I think the link provided by Sergiy above might help.
2. The key point is in the `exportDone(...)` method. Your cleanup code would set the icon of the source component to null.

You will probably need to read the tutorial to understand the concept of these two classes.